# What type of encoding is this?

Tags: encoding, decoding

I am having trouble determing what type of encoding this text is. I have tried different stuff like htmlentities, utf8, urlencode without any luck.

Any of you know what this is:

- Abbas HÃ¼seynov
- Filip OzobiÄ‡
- Mirko IvaniÄ‡
- DuÅ¡anÂ JovanÄiÄ‡
- Å½eljko GavriÄ‡

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know what the text is supposed to be after decoding?  Are you sure it isn't just corrupted?

Comment: Try in Python, e.g. `'Å½eljko GavriÄ‡'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')` returns `'Željko Gavrić'`…

Comment: @josefZ how can I do this in php? I tried to run mb_convert_encoding($str, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8"); two times but the result I got was Željko Gavri? - working on the first character, but the last got turned into ?

Comment: @David Željko Gavrić

Comment: Do not attempt to translate [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) back. Get a text in original encoding instead. It's `UTF-8` in your case. BTW, your code works for me for `$str = "Å½eljko GavriÄ‡";`. Please share how did you get those strings in your [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ well this code mb_convert_encoding("Å½eljko GavriÄ‡", "Windows-1252", "UTF-8"); works fine on JSFiddle, but not on my server so I guess there is something wrong with my server.

On PHPFiddle it outputs: "Željko Gavrić" while on my server it outputs "Å½eljko GavriÄ‡"

Comment: It looks like double-mojibake on your server. Please [edit] the question and give more detailed info about it in a [mcve] (OS, environment, where do you run the code from, other circumstances…). Albeit…  maybe this could be off-topic here so you could ask at https://superuser.com/ rather…